# How Can I Fix Apend Designing Issues In Isotope?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, append

I have append the ajax coding, data are coming fine, here during appending this `style="position: absolute; left: 468px; top: 0px;"` css is not adding to my new append data. How can I do this? Below is my ajax code. Please suggest me.

[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6lml.png)

```js
<?php
 $per_page=20;
   $latestImages = mysql_query("select * from ".GIFIMAGES." WHERE isActive = '1' AND not_update='1'   order by modified ");
  $total_record=mysql_num_rows($latestImages)/5;
$maxPage=number_format((float) $total_record, 2, '.', '');

 ?>
<script>
    var lastX = 0;
            var currentX = 0;
            var page = 1;
            function loadMore() {
            if (page < '<?php echo $maxPage;?>') {
            page++;
            $('#load-more').html('Loading...');
              $.post("ajax_append.php", {'ajax_append':'<?php echo $per_page;?>','page':page},function(data)
         {
                 alert(data);

               $('#homeload').append(data);

                $('#load-more').html('VIEW MORE');
            });
            } else {
            $('#load-more').hide();
            }
            }



</script>
```

Below is external(html) file append coding.(`grid-splash-item`)No css is calling for this same class, which I have been used in pageloading.plz check it.

```html
                <?php
                $i=50; 
                $latestImages = mysql_query("select * from ".GIFIMAGES." WHERE isActive = '1' AND not_update='1'   order by modified DESC limit $total_records,$page_records");


                while($getLatestGif=mysql_fetch_array($latestImages)){
                $i++;
                $categoryName = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select name from ".CATEGORY." where id='".$getLatestGif['cat_id']."'"));
                $checkLatestUsers = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from ". YEAH." where  user_id = '".$_SESSION['USER_ID']."' and gifimageid ='".$getLatestGif['id']."'"));
                $yeahCount = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select gifimageid from ". YEAH ."  where gifimageid = '".$getLatestGif['id']."'"));
                $yeahCountLatest = mysql_query("update ".GIFIMAGES." set yeahCount ='$yeahCount' where id = '".$getLatestGif['id']."'");
                $comment = mysql_query("select * from ".COMMENTS." where gifid='". $getLatestGif['id']."' order by id desc");
                $getLatestUser=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT username,photo FROM ".TBL_USERS." WHERE id='".$getLatestGif['userId']."'"));
                $commnetsCounts = mysql_num_rows($comment);
                ?>
                <div class="grid-splash-item">
                    <!--  <img src="images/img-2.jpg" /> -->
                    <a href="<?php echo HTTP_ROOT.'funny-'.$categoryName['name'].'-images/'. makeSeoUrl($getLatestGif['title']).'/'.$getLatestGif['uniq_id'];?>" >  <img  width="198" height="169" src="<?php echo HTTP_ROOT.DIR_GIF.$getLatestGif['gifphoto'];?>" /> </a>
                    <div class="gif-details">
                        <div class="gif-details-menu">
                            <span>
                                <div class="gif-details-menu-box" <?php if(!empty($_SESSION['USER_ID']) && $checkLatestUsers){?>  <?php } else {?> <?php } ?>>   

                                     //My coding present.I have removed it(too  long).
                                </div>
                            </span>
                            <p><a href="<?php echo HTTP_ROOT.'funny-'.$categoryName['name'].'-images/'. makeSeoUrl($getLatestGif['title']).'/'.$getLatestGif['uniq_id'];?>" title="<?php echo $getLatestGif['title'];?>" rel="tooltip"><?php echo substr($getLatestGif['title'],0,20);?></a></p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
```

Comment: where is the code for the style you want to append?

Comment: It is adding through js ,but after doing append(i  am using it for ajax pagination ),this css is not attaching into that div.I am facing a designing issues.

Comment: on pagination where are you getting the data from?? add the style there.

Comment: I have created a external html page for it,from there i am calling new appended data,but i have alredy tried it adding inline css,but its not working.Please check in screenshort left and top have diffrent values for different grid-splash-item.How can i do it through inline css?plz explain me.Thanxx

Comment: show the code of external html file.

Comment: ok one minute ,i am attaching it.

Comment: I have added it plz check it above.

Comment: why dont you add inline css here `<div class="grid-splash-item">` to <div class="grid-splash-item" style="position: absolute; left: 468px; top: 0px;">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching a lot,i came to a accurate result.Here its only need to change two things.Here i have not written any inline css,after appending its coming fine,with proper css.

Below is my new code.Which is working perfectly.

This is my new script coding.I have modified a little

```
<?php  $per_page=20; $latestImages = mysql_query("select * from ".GIFIMAGES." WHERE isActive = '1' AND not_update='1'   order by modified "); $total_record=mysql_num_rows($latestImages)/5;$maxPage=number_format((float) $total_record, 2, '.', ''); ?>
```

```js
<script>
     $(function(){

            var $container = $('#container');
            var lastX = 0;
            var currentX = 0;
            var page = 1;
            $('#append a').click(function(){
            if (page < '<?php echo $maxPage;?>') {
            page++;
            $('.funny-gifts').html('Loading...');
            $.post("ajax_append.php", {'ajax_append':'<?php echo $per_page;?>','page':page},function(data)
         { 

        // $('#container').append(data);
        var $newItems = $(data);
         $('#container').isotope( 'insert', $newItems );
                   $('.funny-gifts').html('More Funny Gifs');
                  });
                  } else {
                  $('.funny-gifts').hide();
                  }

      });
  });
  </script>




    ***var $newItems = $(data);
     $('#container').isotope( 'insert', $newItems );***
```

This above  two line coding is very important for appending.
Dont use $('#container').append(data); for appending.Result will come but,having a designing issues.Then after it replace the  view more button slightly.Below is coding.

```html
<div    id="append"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="loadMore()" class="funny-gifts">More Funny Gifs</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding the inline css in html only like,

change this

```
<div class="grid-splash-item">
```

to

```
<?php
    $counter = 1;
    while ($getLatestGif = mysql_fetch_array($latestImages)) {
        $i++;
        $categoryName = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select name from " . CATEGORY . " where id='" . $getLatestGif['cat_id'] . "'"));
        $checkLatestUsers = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from " . YEAH . " where  user_id = '" . $_SESSION['USER_ID'] . "' and gifimageid ='" . $getLatestGif['id'] . "'"));
        $yeahCount = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select gifimageid from " . YEAH . "  where gifimageid = '" . $getLatestGif['id'] . "'"));
        $yeahCountLatest = mysql_query("update " . GIFIMAGES . " set yeahCount ='$yeahCount' where id = '" . $getLatestGif['id'] . "'");
        $comment = mysql_query("select * from " . COMMENTS . " where gifid='" . $getLatestGif['id'] . "' order by id desc");
$getLatestUser = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT username,photo FROM " . TBL_USERS . " WHERE id='" . $getLatestGif['userId'] . "'"));
        $commnetsCounts = mysql_num_rows($comment);

        if ($counter % 4 == 1) {
            $style = 'style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 175px;"';
        } else if ($counter % 4 == 2) {
            $style = 'style="position: absolute; left: 234px; top: 175px;"';
        } else if ($counter % 4 == 3) {
            $style='style="position: absolute; left: 468px; top: 175px;"';
        } else {
            $style='style="position: absolute; left: 702px; top: 175px;"';
        }
        $counter++;
?>
<div class="grid-splash-item" <?= $style ?>>
    <!--  <img src="images/img-2.jpg" /> -->
    <a href="<?php echo HTTP_ROOT . 'funny-' . $categoryName['name'] . '-images/' . makeSeoUrl($getLatestGif['title']) . '/' . $getLatestGif['uniq_id']; ?>" >  <img  width="198" height="169" src="<?php echo HTTP_ROOT . DIR_GIF . $getLatestGif['gifphoto']; ?>" /> </a>
    <div class="gif-details">
        <div class="gif-details-menu">
            <span>
                <div class="gif-details-menu-box" <?php if (!empty($_SESSION['USER_ID']) && $checkLatestUsers) { ?>  <?php } else { ?> <?php } ?>>   

                    //My coding present.I have removed it(too  long).
                </div>
            </span>
            <p><a href="<?php echo HTTP_ROOT . 'funny-' . $categoryName['name'] . '-images/' . makeSeoUrl($getLatestGif['title']) . '/' . $getLatestGif['uniq_id']; ?>" title="<?php echo $getLatestGif['title']; ?>" rel="tooltip"><?php echo substr($getLatestGif['title'], 0, 20); ?></a></p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: After adding inline css ,its coming in fire fox,but as here left: 468px; top: 0px;  are same for all the div ,all the data are overlapping with each other.Present in a single place.

Comment: you do u want to split them??

Comment: Yes i want to split them according to grid view design ,which is present previously when ajax append is not occurs.

Comment: you can use counter for that. suppose, `$i = 0;` then style will bw something, $i = 2, change style, maybe if $i% 4 == 0, set $i = 0;, so grid will work.

Comment: Ok i am appling  this one.Thank you

Comment: can you plz give me some demo coding of grid.?

Comment: I have not used it any where.

Comment: @sradha did you check with the answer??

Comment: Top having differnce of 175 between two grid.how can i make it dynamic?plz explain me.

Comment: Thank you for your help,but i have done it another way ,after researching a  lot ,i have modified small things .Its coming perfectly.Below i am posting my answer please check it.

Comment: I have added my result code.I have changed few things.Which is already present in this isotope,only we have to implement it in a proper way.Thank you for your help.